# How to write a query conditionally in laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-query-builder

I am new to the laravel, i am joining three tables based on conditions every thing is working fine but i need to write conditionally if the $field is array it should run with `whereIn` otherwise it should run `where` condition,can you please help me to acheive this thing

```
//$field sometimes it's an array sometimes it's a string.
public function find($field){
      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conditional constraints, you can use the [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#conditional-clauses) clause:

```
$query = DB::table(...);

$data = $query
    ->when(is_array($field), function ($query) use ($field) {
        $query->whereIn('my_field', $field);
    }, function ($query) use ($field) {
        $query->where('my_field', $field);
    })
    ->get();
```

Now, as a tip, you could do this: Wrap the `$fields` variables to an array and then use always the `whereIn` clause. You can achieve this with the [`Arr::wrap()`](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-array-wrap) function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

// ...

$query = DB::table(...);

$data = $query
    ->whereIn('my_field', Arr::wrap($field))
    ->get();
```

PS: I have linked the relevant functions to the docs so you can know how they work and their params.